# Clicking a button in Access Form using VBA Excel

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

This is my code below. I am getting an error "Object doesn't support this property or method" on controls.click. Anyone there who can help?

```
    'create new access object
    Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
    'open the acces project
    Call appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase("D:\NSE Cash\db.accdb")
    appAccess.Visible = True
    With appAccess
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
        .Forms("Form1").Controls("Run").Click
    End With
    Set appAccess = Nothing
```

Comment: A form belongs to an open database, not to the Access application.

Answer (score 1):

First, the button Click event cannot be Private - remove Private from the procedure declaration. Then, this works for me:

`.Forms("Form1").Run_Click`